# Nested attributes not being destroyed after an update validation fails in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I'm struggling to get my head around this myself so I hope I can explain it well. I have a form with nested models. A simplified version of things is as follows (using Rails 3.0.13);

```
#parent.rb

class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, :dependent => destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children, :allow_destroy => true
  validates_presence_of :thing
  validate :children_unique

  def children_unique
    errors[:base] << "You have the same child listed more than once!" if self.children.map{|x| [child.name, child.age]} != self.children.map{|x| [child.name, child.age]}.uniq
  end
end


#child.rb

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parents
end

#parents_controller.rb

class ParentsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :parent   #Using cancan for authorization. This calls @parent = Parent.find(params[:id]); authorize! :update, @parent; at the start of the update method

  def update
    if @parent.update_attributes(params[:operation])
      redirect_to @parent.admission, :notice => 'Operation was updated successfully'
    else
      flash.now[:warning] = "Parent was NOT updated!"
      render :action => "edit"
    end
  end
end
```

All pretty standard so far. My form is set up in a pretty standard way as well. I call `parent_form.fields_for :children` and render a partial for the children within the fields_for block. Each child partial form contains a delete link and when it is clicked javascript is used to set a hidden field so an attribute of _destroy is set to "1" and the partial is hidden from view.

This works well in most instances but the odd problem I have found is as follows;

If I am editing an existing parent that already has, say, 2 children, and I delete 1 of those children and then set 'thing' to be blank the form fails validation as expected (because 'thing' is not present) and the edit view is re-rendered. In the view that results, the child that I deleted is present again! Its hidden _destroy field is set to "true" and if I fill out 'thing' again and submit the form, the updated parent only has 1 child.

I dealt with this by adding a conditional style tag to the nested child div `<div class='fields'<%= " style='display: none;'" if f.object._destroy %>>` so it would no longer appear if it was deleted before attempting to update the record. This achieves its aim but, if I do this and submit the form without correcting the empty 'thing' field so the model fails validation again, and in the next edit form that appears I add a new child identical to the one that was previously deleted and fill out the 'thing' field, the model now fails the `children_unique` validation even though the first of the identical children has the _delete attribute set to "true".

Clearly I have tied myself up in knots here and I have tried a vast array of alternative approaches and modifications and this is the best I have come up with so far. It's very very close but I still have this weird edge case that will probably never actually happen in practice but which suggests I don't quite understand the way my controller and models are interacting.

Can someone set me straight?

Answer (score 1):

You should make the delete link be an ajax call to a controller that deletes the child right away and removes it's markup from the page, this way, even if validation really fails you will have already removed it and none of these two issues will happen.

Comment: That's a good idea - I'd really hoped not to go down the ajax pathway in this app at all but it would fix the problem.

Comment: You can do it without AJAX, in the controller at the beginning of the update action.

Answer (score 1):

To understand what's going on, we first need to look at how Rails handles database interaction. Namely, Rails wraps all database interaction in a transaction, so that if something fails, everything is reverted. That's why you'll see "ROLLBACK" in your logs when there's a validation error. It tried to commit the change, but there was an error, so it rolled it back. No harm done.

Similarly, when you're manipulating parent records and children records in the same form, it's all handled in a transaction. This is actually a great thing. If something fails, you don't want a few changes to go through and one to fail.

Whenever you set `_destroy` to true, you're simply marking that child record for destruction. However, this destruction doesn't happen immediately. Instead, the child lingers until the parent is saved (`save` returns true). In your case, this isn't happening: the call to `save` is failing because of the validation error. This is a good thing, however: if your parent record fails to save, there should be no reason that the child record should be deleted.

That being said, my recommendation would be to wrap those child records in a `div`, add a data element, say `data-destroy`, which is set to the attribute `_destroy`. Whenever the delete link is clicked, set it to true, and whenever the page is loaded make sure that all `div`s that have `data-destroy` set to true are hidden.

Hope this helps you understand what's going on under the hood!

Comment: That's definitely a helpful explanation, and in line with what I thought was going on. I don't quite follow what you're suggesting with the data-destroy element though. How is that used to ensure the child isn't processed?

Comment: The use of the data-destroy element was merely a means of hiding the appropriate divs containing children marked for destruction. It's all UI.

Comment: I'm already doing that by setting the .fields div style to display:none though. It's not the displaying that's the problem, it's the _destroy not being observed when the model is updated.

Answer (score 1):

Beside adding `hide` on `deleted` records on user side you can add in the model custom validation `children.reject(&:marked_for_destruction?)` to skip those hidden